# *** glibc detected *** ms2: free(): invalid pointer: 0xb7526ff4 ***

Tags: c++, pointers

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to correct it as I am given no errors in my code editors. I have looked up similar issues, but I am still having trouble to understand how to apply the solutions here. I've tried altering my code for several hours now, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. I have provided my .h and .cpp files below.

ErrorMessage.h

```
#ifndef SICT_ERRORMESSAGE_H
#define SICT_ERRORMESSAGE_H
#include <iostream>

namespace sict {
    class ErrorMessage {
        char* message_; //pointer that holds the address of the message stored in current object
    public:
        explicit ErrorMessage(const char* errorMessage = nullptr); //receive address of a C-style nullterminate string holding an error message
        ErrorMessage(const ErrorMessage& em) = delete; //deleted copy constructor that prevents copying of an ErrorMessage object
        ErrorMessage& operator=(const ErrorMessage& em) = delete; //deleted assignment operator that prevents assignment of ErrorMessage object to current object
        virtual ~ErrorMessage(); //deallocates any memory that has been dynamically allocated by the current object
        void clear(); //clears any message stored by current object and initialize object to safe, empty state
        bool isClear() const; //return true if object is in a safe, empty state
        void message(const char* str); //stores a copy of the C-style string pointed to by str
        const char* message() const; //return address of the message stored in current object
    };
    //helper operator
      std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ErrorMessage& err);
}
#endif
```

ErrorMessage.cpp

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "ErrorMessage.h"

namespace sict {

    ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage(const char* errorMessage) {
    if(errorMessage == nullptr) {
        message_ = nullptr;
    }
    else {
            message(errorMessage);
    }
    }

    ErrorMessage::~ErrorMessage() {
    delete [] message_;
    }

    void ErrorMessage::clear() {
    delete [] message_;
    message_ = nullptr;
    }

    bool ErrorMessage::isClear() const {
        if(message_ == nullptr) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void ErrorMessage::message(const char* str) {
        delete [] message_;
        message_ = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
        strcpy(message_, str);
    }

    const char* ErrorMessage::message() const {
        return message_;
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ErrorMessage& err) {
    if(!err.isClear()) {
          os << err.message();
    }
    return os;
    }
}
```

Comment: now, really, it's C++, do you have any valid reason to do all this stuff instead that using `std::string`?

Comment: If you expect that a clean bill of health of a code editor means that your program is bug-free, that you're really in for a shocker. Also, it's obvious that there is more to your program than the shown code; so why exactly do you believe the problem lies in the shown code, and not in other parts of your code?

Comment: The only other part of the code is the main file, but it is not to be altered in any way, which means the fault lies in the code above

Comment: Ah. Actually, the error is rather obvious. You can only `delete` what you have `new`ed. No exceptions. Now, the shown code `delete`s something in the destructor. Can you point out to me which part of your constructor `new`s, what the destructor is expected to `delete`?

Comment: My guess is you are creating an `ErrorMessage` object with an invalid pointer. It is then sending that to the `message()` function which attempts to delete it.

Comment: You might better to assign null to message_ at the first place before  checking it.

Comment: I know the issue lies with the delete [], yet no matter what I do with any of them I am met with some kind of memory error. This is getting very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

It's not surprising your code made it through editor syntax checks and compilation - it's valid code.  It's just got an *incorrect* pointer somewhere.

This may mean that your'e accidentally dereferencing something , or perhaps passing a value somewhere you should be passing a pointer.  You should get a compile time warning about that kind of stuff.

Another possibility is that you're failing to initialize some pointer, and its value happens to be `0xb75...`.

Clearly, neither you nor I are not likely to guess from whence this error originates.  As Sam Varshavchik pointed out in a comment, you don't even know if  the code you posted is the source of the error.   Even if you guess your way through this one ( or perhaps keenly observe, Sam ), it's just plain silly to try to write C++ that way.

What you need is a debugger.  A debugger is a program you run your program *within*, and it keeps track of the program's state so that when you have a memory violation, the debugger can produce a *backtrace* showing where in your source code the error occurred.  You also have to compile your program *with debugging support*, so that the debugger has markers it can use to refer back to the source code.

It's a process far beyond the scope of your question, but one that's easy to learn about once you know what you're going for.  Look for one that integrates with your IDE, if possible, as you're leveraging your development environment heavily.  It's not unlikely that you already have it set up- you might just need to use it.  Search for C++ debugging in the context of your editor first - if it turns up nothing, consider searching under your compiler suite, whatever that may be ( if your'e using open source, you're probably using gcc, and the matching debugger is `gdb` ).

You're about to gain a far more accurate understanding of what it is to program C / C++.  Good luck.

Comment: Very well answered..!